# How can I compile code on the Bixby studio SDK using an Emulator?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

After installing the Bixby Studio, How do I compile the code and where can I find the emulator to display my compiled code ? Does the Bixby studio support an emulator ?

Answer (score 1):

Bixby developer studio is the only tool for bixby capsule development.

You might begin with the quick start, if you haven't already worked through it.

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/get-started